# Filter two dates in one query django/python

Tags: django, python-2.7, date, filter, models

Is there a way I can filter two datefield columns from a table on the same query?

Example:

I have date_ots and date_lta I need to filter and get the result from today + 4 days on both columns.

Thanks for your attention,

Alex

Comment: Assuming you want it exactly equal to, you can do: `Model.objects.filter(date_ots=(timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=4)), date_lta=(timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=4)))`

Comment: oh let me try it out. give me a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like exact timing (hours, min, sec), you can do:

```
from datetime import timedelta

four_days_from_now = timezone.now() + timedelta(days=4)
query = Model.objects.filter(date_ots=four_days_from_now, date_lta=four_days_from_now)
```

If you only want the date 4 days from now (at any time), you can do:

```
from datetime import timedelta

four_days_from_now = timezone.now().date() + timedelta(days=4)
query = Model.objects.filter(date_ots=four_days_from_now, date_lta=four_days_from_now)
```

Comment: Thanks actually I did it this way declare the variable with the range date and did the search, Thanks :D for your time.